# overflow:hidden but container still has no height value

Tags: containers, overflow

I'm using overflow:hidden inside a container div with 4 floats inside, so that the container extends with the floats:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

but with when the 4th div has height:100% it doesn't extend to the bottom, in fact it's just a flat line, anyone know how to solve that issue?

eg

```
<div style="border:1px solid green; width: 1000px;margin:0 auto;overflow:auto;">    
    <div style="float:left;display:block;width:200px;height:500px;border:1px solid orange;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;display:block;width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid orange;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;display:block;width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid orange;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;display:block;width:100px;height:100%;border:1px solid black;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the height of your container div for the `100%` to fill the whole container.  You see, `100%` is relative to the container it is in.  Therefore, `%`'s are and taking the percentage of it's container.